# Change title color of bootstrap vue tab title

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using bootstrap-vue.js to create a tab. The result is like this
[image]

I just want change the tab title color because it's using default color from my project. And from the bootstrap-vue.js official link (https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/tabs) there is a title-item-class for making any change in the tab title. So I crate the code like this :

```
<b-tab title="Transaction History" title-item-class="tab-title-class">
```

and my css :

```
.tab-title-class {
    color: #FF0000 !important;  
}
```

But it doesn't give any effect. So what is the problem here ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have any warnings in your console ?..

Comment: No... there is no warning or errors @Naveen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `v-bind` directive to apply the custom class and also use a quote to denote it's a string:

```
<b-tab title="Transaction History" :title-item-class="'tab-title-class'">
```

`:title-item-class` is just an alias for `v-bind:title-item-class`

It's because bootstrap vue uses `props` not simple html attributes. Where `title` is simply the html attribute and you don't need to use `v-bind`.

---

But I think, you need to apply `:title-link-class`. It's because link tag is being applied there.

```
<b-tab title="Transaction History" :title-link-class="'tab-title-class'">
```

While using `v-bind`, it checks for the types for the input. If that is undefined, then you'll get error. So, here we don't have such class defined in the `data` option but simply assigning a string class for css which will work fine.

Comment: I have tried this one. But still nothing change... The color is still pinky.. @-@

Comment: oooh... wait. I got an error message when putting :

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I got this error  "Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "titleItemClass". Expected String, Array, Object, got Number."

Comment: See updated answer... In the example of bootstrap vue... there I see using :title-link-class instead.

Comment: Can you try applying this class just for now: `bg-primary` to check if it works.

Comment: Thanks... :title-link-class is working... 
Thanks a lot mr. Bhojendra Nepal.. B-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a colon before `title-item-class`. Try
`<b-tab title="Transaction History" :title-item-class="tab-title-class">`

Comment: I have tried this one. But still nothing change... The color is still pinky.. @-@

Answer (score 0):

if you are using style inside the same template like following,

```
<style>
.tab-title-class {
    color: #FF0000 !important;  
}
</style>
```

this will show warning in your console like,

> "[Vue warn]: Templates should only be responsible for mapping the
>   state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your
>   templates, such as < style >. "

and those styles are not parsed.

use this style in some external css to work.

also use v-bind for the class

```
<b-tab title="Transaction History" :title-item-class="tab-title-class">
```

Comment: I got this error "Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "titleItemClass". Expected String, Array, Object, got Number."