# bootstrap-vue change tabs title background color only

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Am already had a navbar and a tags tabs, all works good with my styling, now am trying to convert it to bootstrap-vue. non is working.
Start simple, i followed this question here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49105258/change-title-color-of-bootstrap-vue-tab-title][1]
but the styling does not change. what would be the right way, to change only the background color of titles for all tabs, and make it act as sticky menue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long search i got help. and all i wanted is to use

```
::v-deep {}
```

on my styling.